# Information entropy of a mixture distribution

Tags: entropy, information-theory, mixture-distribution

I'm working with a high-dimensional mixture distribution, and I'm interested in calculating its entropy.

I think I could work it out if there were only two mixture components.  Following @Daniel's suggestion in the comments, here's what I have so far:

> If the two components had equal weight, I think the answer would be $\frac{1}{2}(H_1 + H_2 - I_{1,2})$, where $H_1$ and $H_2$ are the entropies of the component distributions and $I_{1,2}$ is the mutual information between them. My logic is that subtracting the mutual information prevents double-counting any entropy.

With a bit more work, I could probably figure out how to generalize it to unequal weights.
But my problem involves thousands of mixture components, and I don't know how I'd go about accounting for all of them.

Comment: Maybe you can write the equations, up the point you have solved?

Comment: @Daniel Good idea.  I've added what I have so far.

Comment: What to you think about this? 
$\sum_i H_i - \sum_{i,j} I_{i,j}$ multiplied by some constant

Comment: I don't understand the question (could you refine what is data or information your start with and your goal?), but you might find the [Venn diagram on Mutual Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information) enlightening.

Comment: why would subtracting mutual information prevent double-counting when $I$ itself is made up both of the preceding two entropies? It looks more like it will just cancel the $H$'s completely, leaving you left with only conditional entropy in the brackets